# Is there analogs for Win+1, Win+2,... Win+T hotkeys in RDP client?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, hotkeys, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm RDPing from Windows 10 to Windows Server 2012 R2 with "Apply Windows key combinations" option set to "On this computer" (I got used to this variant). I know about such RDP client hotkeys as Alt+Home, Alt+PgUp/PgDn and so on ([List of hotkeys on MSDN for unknown Windows version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500(v=vs.85).aspx)).

So, I wonder **is there** any **RDP client analogues for** such relatively modern Windows shortcuts as **Win+1, Win+2,... Win+T, Win+S**? and for good old **Win+E, Win+D, Win+M** ones?

Comment: "with "Apply Windows key combinations" option set to "On this computer"" You choosing this option is what's preventing them from working.  Change that to one of the other options and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I know that "On this computer" will make all Windows hotkeys to be processed on the remote machine and resolve my issue. But this configuration is inconvenient for me. Usually I don't spend much time in RDP sessions, I often switch to local apps and back to RDP, it can be several simultaneous RDP sessions, I prefer to use keyboard rather then mouse where it is possible. So I'd like to keep Alt+Tab to be a simple and familiar way to switch between apps on local machine (RDP client is one of this apps). Also I use VirtuaWin quite a lot and it's hotkeys breaks with this config.

Comment: I've made a mistake in my previous comment: instead of "On this computer" I should write "On the remote computer".